# Not to reload page on a link click

Tags: jsf

I have a design which consists of images for links.
They must work like a select component, for example when i click one link, in the back side i control which one is selected.
After user want to commit his/her changes he/she click a submit button and save the selections.

So i need a `h:blahblah` component for get selection that does not reload page when user click it, and maybe click again to unselect maybe click again to select again.

I need `h:` component because i can change only their css easily.

I also will be glad if you share your advises on how can i achive this job too.

Thanks

---

**SOLVED** by my colleague

```
<h:outputLink value="javascript:void(0);"><p:ajax event="click"  
                    listener="#{beanView.method()}"/>My Link</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html#Table4_20 here jsf tags for selection, you can handle values changing like 'value={#myBean.selectedItemString}' and you can add selectedItemString as private String into your bean class then you can access via getters and setters also check primefaces : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<f:ajax>` in combination with a `@ViewScoped` managed bean for this. Let the `listener` of `<f:ajax>` set the selected image value. You can just nest `<f:ajax>` inside `<h:graphicImage>`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:graphicImage name="image1.png">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.setSelectedImage('image1')}" />
    </h:graphicImage>
    <h:graphicImage name="image2.png">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.setSelectedImage('image2')}" />
    </h:graphicImage>
    <h:graphicImage name="image3.png">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.setSelectedImage('image3')}" />
    </h:graphicImage>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private String selectedImage;

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(selectedImage);
    }

    // ...
}
```